# Does workflow status change gets triggered when creating new objects in Plone?

Tags: workflow, plone, contentrules

I have a content rule, that sends emails whenever an object is published (any of the states internally_published, visible, externally_published, ...).

Upon request of my client, I have changed the local workflow policy to one whose initial state is one the published; but then creating a new object does not send the desired email. Only when I manually change the status, the emails is sent.

Does Plone triggers the "status change" event when a new object is created? Is this a bug? Should I be thinking to it differently?

Details: I'm using Plone 4.0.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use a different rule for this: try sending the email when an object is added to a folder.

for more information, take a look at [Using Content Rules](https://plone.org/documentation/kb/using-content-rules/tutorial-all-pages) tutorial.

Comment: I see, so I need a couple of rules: one when the object is added (conditioned by its state also); and another for the change in state.